# How to test the bcrypt compare function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, bcrypt

I'm using this dependency: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt.

And I'm trying to test this function:

```js
VolunteerSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function (email, password) {
    var Volunteer = this
    var foundVolunteer

    return Volunteer.findOne({email}).then((volunteer) => {
        if (volunteer) {
            foundVolunteer = volunteer
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, volunteer.password)
        } else {
            return Promise.reject({error: "Email not found"})
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response) {
            console.log("Sending found vol", foundVolunteer)
            return Promise.resolve(foundVolunteer)
        } else {
            return Promise.reject({error: "Incorrect password"})
        }
    })
};
```

with the following test in jest:

```js
test('Valid credentials', async () => {
        var volunteerValid = new Volunteer({
            name : 'Test Time',
            phone: '1111111111',
            password: 'test password',
            email : 'abc@xyz.com'
        })

        await volunteerValid.save()
        await expect(Volunteer.findByCredentials('abc@xyz.com', 'test password')).resolve.toEqual(volunteerValid)
    })
```

The problem that I'm encountering is that the function returns the volunteer after the test has been executed even though I use async-await in my test.

Also, for this line of code:

```js
console.log("Sending found vol", foundVolunteer)
```

Jest gives me the error: Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

Can you please help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: I am not familiar with the override that would allow you to put a promise inside `expect`. Did you try to `await` inside `expect` so that `expect` gets the awaited value of the `findByCredentials`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing sync and async mode into your function ( findByCredentials ) ,  you could declare the findByCredentials to be async and use await on async invocations

```
VolunteerSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async function (email, password) {
  var Volunteer = this

  // TODO consider to put a try catch when you call findOne method
  let volunteer = await Volunteer.findOne({email})
  if(!volunteer){
    throw new Error({error: "Email not found"})
  }
  if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, volunteer.password)) {
    console.log("Sending found vol", volunteer)
    return volunteer
  } else {
    throw new Error({error: "Incorrect password"})
  }
};
```